# How to add unique scrolling effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a scrolling effect similar to  ones used in apple pages such [this one](https://www.apple.com/iphone-13-pro/). How would I do that using HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Comment: What specific effect are you looking to reproduce? Where are you stuck? What difficulties have you had when you tried to recreate that effect?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `webkit` to access the elements inside the browser and customize them at your own discretion.

```css
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: var(--scrollbar);
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 10000px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can access this element using `-webkit-scrollbar` and design the scrollbar location using `-webkit-scrollbar-track` and design the scrollbar itself using `-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`.

> Also, do not look for ready-made code inside the StackOverFlow, it is
> better to learn how to use it.

Comment: Isn't `webkit` only on Chrome and Safari, and non-standard?

Comment: It seems the most logical way and I do not think there is a problem in this regard. Most open source projects use this way.

Comment: Most open source projects use this AND other options for better browser support. If you are aware of any kind of `scrollbar` or `scrollbar-track` or `scrollbar-thumb` just without the `webkit` that is a standard then that would work perfectly.